# Query IN (2,3,4) with Kohana ORM

Tags: php, mysql, select, kohana, where-clause

I'm tying to do the following mysql with Kohana ORM:

```
SELECT column_id FROM tables WHERE column_id IN (2, 3, 6)
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using:

```
->and_where('column_id', 'in', $args())
```

Decided to stick with ORM db methods instead of kohana's database query builders.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following syntax in kohana ORM:

```
in()
```

Creates an IN portion of a query. 
It has three parameters:
1.the column to match 
2.an array or string of values to match against (boolean),
3. to create a NOT clause instead

```
$db->in('title', array(1,2,3,4,5));
```

This generates: `title IN ('1','2','3','4','5')`

Comment: Interesting. I don't see IN() in ORM::_db_methods array, and I'm getting an error saying that the method doesn't exist.

Comment: use this link for reference [link] http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/database/builder#in

Answer (score 1):

If `tables` is the name of your table, try something like

```
$rows = ORM::factory('tables')->in('column_id', array(2, 3, 6))->find_all();
```

Since `in()` is failing for you through the ORM, this should work in the interim:

```
$rows = DB::select()->from('tables')->where('column_id', 'IN', array(2, 3, 6));
```

Comment: The documentation is here: http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/database/builder#where

Comment: hmm, I'm get this error: Invalid method in called in Model_Tables. So, pretty much the _in_ method is not defined in Kohana_ORM.

Comment: Nice. I was just going to add this link with useful examples: http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/database/query/builder